# Ocelot .NET API gateway: Failed to load API definition

Tags: .net, swagger, api-gateway, ocelot

I used Ocelot to build .Net API gateway. I combined the CatchAll style and Aggregate in my  configuration and got the error when runing gateway:

[image]

Please help to guide me to fix the problem.
Below is my Routing configuration. The first routing is used for aggregate request and the second is Catch All style:

```
"Routes": [  {
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderservice/Order/GeAllOrders",
    "DownstreamScheme": "https",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": 7028
    }
    ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderservice/Order/GeAllOrders",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ],
    "Key": "GeAllOrders",
    "SwaggerKey": "orderservice",
},{
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderservice/{everything}",
    "DownstreamScheme": "https",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": 7028
    }
    ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderservice/{everything}",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ],
    "SwaggerKey": "orderservice",
},]
```

If I remove the second route (Catch All style), the error was fixed. However, I want to use the Catch All style to reduce the configuration.

This is [my source code](https://github.com/nngochue/MicroserviceApp).

Comment: The exception states a deserialization error, and the stack trace says it is Swagger, not Ocelot.  You seem to have a repeated property somewhere.

Comment: If I remove the second routing (Catch All style), the error was fixed. So I think it's because of my routing configuration.

Comment: Did you try to give another name to the above configuration  like : `"SwaggerKey": "orderservice_get_all_orders",`